# How to solve "Forbidden: You don't have permission (For Bugzilla)"?

Tags: bugzilla, forbidden

**Disclaimer:** I have read most of the articles in this forum regarding this one (I know there are quite a many of them). And since none of the fixes listed here could help me I thought asking a new question.

**System:**

I have the bitnami lampstack installed in ubuntu 12.10 server edition. I have testlink module isnatlled in it.

I am trying to install bugzilla on top of this lampstack (not the default one) which I will later integrate with testlink.
I have successfully installed bugzilla with all its dependencies on this stack. But when i try to access the site using URL I am getting the "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /bugzilla/ on this server." error.

I am using the  basic structure folder:
- apps/myapp
            |- htdocs
            |- conf

I have done the following.

- Have included the following lines in "/opt/lampstack-5.4.11-1/apps/bugzilla/conf/bugzilla.conf"

> Alias /bugzilla/ "/opt/lampstack-5.4.11-1/apps/bugzilla/htdocs/"
>
> Alias /bugzilla "/opt/lampstack-5.4.11-1/apps/bugzilla/htdocs"
>
> ```
> Options +MultiViews
>
> AllowOverride All
>
> <IfVersion < 2.3 >
>
> Order allow,deny
>
> Allow from all
>
> </IfVersion>
>
> <IfVersion >= 2.3>
>
> Require all granted
>
> </IfVersion> </Directory>
> ```

- I have added the following in "/opt/lampstack-5.4.11-1/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"

> Include "/opt/lampstack-5.4.11-1/apps/bugzilla/conf/bugzilla.conf"

And then I have religiously restarted the server.
And still I am getting teh forbidden error. I have tried almost every fix I could find.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Besides using a "LAMP stack"? What version of Apache do you have?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have apache2. For both of them. The normal apache2 is running on port 80